# SpriteKit tracking multiple touches

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, touchesbegan

I have several buttons that move a main character. (Left, right, jump, etc.) But, when I touch more than one button at a time, the previous one is ended. My question is, how do I keep both touches alive for the duration of their touches? As an example, this would allow the character to move forward and jump at the same time. I have set multipleTouchEnabled to true. I've read that using a dictionary to track touches would help, but I can't seem to wrap my head around the implementation.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInView(nil)

            if location.x < self.size.width / 2 && location.y > self.size.height / 2 {
                movingLeft = true
            }
            if location.x > self.size.width / 2 && location.y > self.size.height / 2 {
                movingRight = true
            }
            if location.x < self.size.width / 2 && location.y < self.size.height / 2 {
                jump()
            }
            if location.x > self.size.width / 2 && location.y < self.size.height / 2 {
                jump()
            }
        }
    }

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        movingLeft = false
        movingRight = false
    }

func jump() {
    mainCharacter.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
    mainCharacter.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 400))
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The logic

You should create a dictionary of active touches.

```
private var activeTouches = [UITouch:String]()
```

Every time a touch begins you save it into the dictionary and assign to it a label.

```
activeTouches[touch] = "left"
```

So when the touch does end you can search for it into your dictionary and  find the related label. Now you know which button has been released by the user.

```
let button = activeTouches[touch]
if button == "left" { ... }
```

*And don't forget to remove it from the dictionary.*

```
activeTouches[touch] = nil
```

### The implementation

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    private var activeTouches = [UITouch:String]()

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
            let button = findButtonName(from:touch)
            activeTouches[touch] = button
            tapBegin(on: button)
        }
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
            guard let button = activeTouches[touch] else { fatalError("Touch just ended but not found into activeTouches")}
            activeTouches[touch] = nil
            tapEnd(on: button)
        }
    }

    private func tapBegin(on button: String) {
        print("Begin press \(button)")
        // your custom logic goes here
    }

    private func tapEnd(on button:String) {
        print("End press \(button)")
        // your custom logic goes here
    }


    private func findButtonName(from touch: UITouch) -> String {
        // replace this with your custom logic to detect a button location
        let location = touch.locationInView(self.view)
        if location.x > self.view?.frame.midX {
            return "right"
        } else {
            return "left"
        }
    }
}
```

In the code above you should put your own code into

1. `tapBegin`: this method receive the label of a button and start some action.

   > E.g. start running.
2. `tapEnd`: this method receive the label of a button and stop some action.

   > E.g. stop running.
3. `findButtonName`: this method receives a `UITouch` and returns the label of the button pressed by the user.

### Test

I tested the previous code on my iPhone. I performed the following actions.

1. **started** pressing the **right** of the screen
2. **started** pressing the **left** of the screen
3. **removed** finger from the **right** of the screen
4. **removed** finger from the **left** of the screen

As you can see in the following log the code is capable of recognizing  different touches

```
Begin press right
Begin press left
End press right
End press left
```

### Conclusion

I hope I made myself clear. Let me know if something is not.

Comment: Why store the touches in a dictionary though? If I remove that code it still works.

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

For me it was a bit foolish but there's an option that I miss to enable in my storyboard in order to handle multiple touch in my GameScene of type `SKScene`.

When one of the overwritten functions is being called, you should have more than 1 `touch` contained in `touches`.

Those functions are indeed:

- `touchesBegan`
- `touchesMoved`
- `touchesEnded`
- `touchesCancelled`

... and the way to retrieve the touches is indeed to browse through them. However, if you are only able to retrieve one touch only, follow the steps bellow.

### Debugging

Here's what you can do to see if you have multiple touches in your set of `touches`:

```swift
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for (i, t) in touches.enumerated() {
            print(i, t.location(in: self))
            self.touchMoved(toPoint: t.location(in: self))    
        }
    }
```

**Output:**
There you should find a `0` for the first touch and a `1` when you touch with 2 fingers... and so on.

### Solution

I case you encounter the same problem than me and have only the touch `t` at index 0 but no other touch, you should see upper in the hierarchy of views if all of them are enabled for multi-touch. In my case it was the view containing the `GameScene` of type `SKScene` that did not have the option `Multiple Touch` enabled. See below:

[image: option to enable multi-touch in the view and its SK instances]